# Visual C++ vs MFC

Tags: windows, user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

Before asking this question on this platform, I have googled and read a couple of books.

**My Understanding So Far:**

I understand that MFC is a framework for the development of GUI applications in Windows. MFC utilizes the Visual C++ library, which can be considered as a wrapper library around Windows APIs.

**Confusions**

1. If I read a book on MFC, it starts talking about Visual C++ (for example `CString` class)
2. If I read a book on Visual C++, it starts explaining GUI development without actually explaining the different classes/templates
3. But I do not find a book that explains the classes of Visual C++ separately.

**Questions:**

- ***Are Visual C++ and MFC the same thing?*** If NO, then where can I find the description of Visual C++ classes only (without GUI development text)?
- Are Visual C++ and Visual Studio related?

Comment: https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/V/Visual_C_plus_plus.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Visual C++"* is the name of the compiler and IDE. It emerged, before Visual Studio had been invented, incorporating several programming languages into a single product.

MFC ships with Visual C++/Visual Studio, and is a class library that both acts as a framework, as well as a resource wrapper for the flat C-based Windows API.

There's a [Hierarchy Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/hierarchy-chart) for most MFC classes on Microsoft's documentation site, as well as a list of [MFC Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/mfc-classes). There is no physical or logical separation between GUI classes and non-GUI classes.

Comment: Thanks but in the following book's description, it says, " `Visual C++ is an established development language for Windows desktop applications.`". Book Link: https://www.amazon.de/dp/1847195563/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=mfc+visual+c%2B%2B&qid=1583252446&sr=8-3

Comment: @use: Visual C++ (the compiler) predates C++ as an international standard. It implemented a fair amount of non-standard behavior, as well as language extensions. At those times, *"Visual C++"* was frequently used to describe the compiler's implementation of the language, to disambiguate it from C++. Today, Microsoft's compilers are as compliant as any other C++ compiler; there's no term (and no need) to describe Microsoft's language implementation. It's just C++.

Comment: Also, don't over complicate it. C++ is a "language" Visual C++ is encompassing GUI into the mix with a drag n drop IDE. https://www.amazon.com/Teach-Yourself-Visual-Days-Sams/dp/0672303728

Comment: @user2756695 As Andrew said, don't over complicate it. C++ is a programming language. Visual C++ is a tool (program), an implementation of the C++ compiler and many other tools to build programs/libraries on the Windows platform. MFC is an object oriented C++ wrapper (frameword) for the Windows API which is written in C--or at least a C API.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: I have this book and this is exactly the book that confused me. The title of the book is `Teach Yourself Visual C++ in 21 Days`, but from the very begining, the book starts talking about GUI development using MFC. If the book is about Visual C++ then why is it trying to teach GUI using MFC?

Comment: That question has already been answered: *"MFC ships with Visual C++"*. It's not surprising that a book about Visual C++ also covers the libraries that come with the compiler/IDE, all the more since MFC is the *only* officially supported, first-party C++ library for GUI programming on Windows (at least prior to the introduction of the Windows Runtime/XAML). A note on the credibility of the book you are used: [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](https://norvig.com/21-days.html).

Comment: I enjoyed the book as a resource at the time. I have other ones. Was it Visual C++ Unleased? That was great too.