# How to differentiate between MFC Classes and User-defined classes

Tags: windows, mfc

I am learning MFC. If I am not wrong, the names of all the MFC classes ***start with the capital letter "C"*** (e.g. `CFrameWnd`, `CFile`, `CMenu`, etc.)

I found that the code generated by the Visual Studio wizard for MFC based project gives similar names to the user-defined classes. For example, if I name my project as "Shapes" then, the classes generated for the project contains classes such as `CShapesApp`, `CMainFrame`, `CChildView`, etc.

In the end, you would have several classes in your project, which may look like `CShapesApp`, `CFrameWnd`, `CMainFrame`, `CWinApp`, `CWnd`, etc.

**QUESTIONS:** For me, the names of the classes (user-defined and MFC library) seem quite similar and hard to differentiate if it is a user-defined class or an MFC library class.

- Why MFC based projects choose such naming conventions (i.e. ***why to put "C" in front of the user-defined classes***)?
- How can I easily differentiate between MFC library classes and user-defined classes?

**UPDATE:** I know that I can change the names and I have already tried that. But the general convention is to start the class names with **"C"** even for the user-defined classes and my question is why? and how can I differentiate easily?

Comment: You can rename yours however you want. If you rerun the application wizard, you can used the Generated Classes list and rename them there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/generated-classes-mfc-application-wizard?view=vs-2019

Comment: The `C` in front of class name is purely an MFC convention. You can name your identifiers as you like. The advantage of have the `C` is you see immediately that it's a class name. This was quite an advantage 15 years or so ago, but it's less relevant with today's intelligent editors.

Comment: Generally, Microsoft uses prefixes to help you know what the name is used for -- C is class.  It's to help differentiate the name among other things that it could be (like a global variable, a function, etc).  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: You can differentiate easily by using your own prefix. There is no reason you need to keep the C if you don't want to

Comment: @LouFranco: Thanks, I know that I can change the names but the general convention is to put the "C" in front. I have to deal with the legacy code which is written using this convention and for me, it is quite confusing to differentiate between MFC and user-defined classes.

Comment: We utilize a toolkit that puts its product's TLA (3 letter acronym) in front of its classes, e.g. CTLATreeCtrl.  I've done the same with our company TLA for similar "library" extension classes.  I still use the C prefix, but the next two or 3 letters show me the library source.  To extend that to ALL user created classes, you may want to differentiate between your own "library extension" classes vs. leaf classes, e.g. CTLAResizeDialog vs. CMyDialog.  Not sure what you might want to use instead of "My" for leaf classes.

Answer (score 1):

> Why MFC based projects choose such naming conventions (i.e. why to put "C" in front of the user-defined classes)?

That's impossible to answer. At a guess, that was just the common thing to do, back in the early 90's. Namespaces were added to C++ in 1995, i.e. years after work on MFC had started, so MFC wound up in the global namespace. Using a `C` prefix for classes reduces the chance for symbols to clash with the Windows API and SDK headers.

> How can I easily differentiate between MFC library classes and user-defined classes?

MFC classes *are* user-defined classes. It is not immediately clear, why you need to differentiate between user-defined classes provided by MFC and user-defined classes provided by your code. If you find this useful, there's no shortcut. You just have to memorize which ones belong to MFC.

There are, however, 2 sets of classes in MFC, for which it is helpful to know, which set they are in: The 'original' classes, and the classes introduced with Visual Studio 2008 (I believe), that offer a wider set of functionality. You can distinguish between those sets by looking at the prefix: The 'original' classes start with `C` (like `CButton`), and the updated classes have a `CMFC` prefix (like `CMFCButton`).

Comment: "You just have to memorize which ones belong to MFC"..ok, that's what I wanted to know because to me, `CMainFrame` and `CFrameWnd` sounds more or less similar and similarly `CWinApp` and `CMainApp` sounds similar.

Comment: @use: You still haven't explained, why you need to know, whether any given type is user-authored or library-provided. I find that distinction somewhat artificial.

Comment: For your reference, this is the MFC class list from visual studio 2019 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/mfc-classes?view=vs-2019

Comment: This has been posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60511325/1889329) to a question by the same author recently (including a link to hierarchy charts).

Comment: @IInspectable: I need to learn how to differentiate easily because I quite often find the creation of object instances of both MFC classes and user-defined classes. And, due to similar names, I have to look for the definitions quite often to find out if it is user-defined or MFC based. If it is user-defined then, I need to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

The "C" prefix convention is a question of your taste. But remind, all MFC-derived classes "are" in fact MFC classes - in the sense of inheritance meaning a derived class "is" also the ancestor. So don't forget your CWnd-derived CMyWnd has everything a CWnd also has.
My personal approach for naming (which I introduced in several dev teams) is to use the "C" prefix for all MFC-derived classes and use another one (or even none) on non-MFC-derived classes.